# How do I implement hook_page_alter() in a module?

Tags: 7

I'm trying to add a piece on content to the `$page['content']` variable, but it's just not working and the examples are not helping me. My code is the following:

```
function my_modulename_page_alter(&$page) {
    $page['content'] = $extracontent . $page['content'];
}
```

`dpm()` doesn't allow me to see the available variables. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [hook_page_build(&$page)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7). [hook_page_alter(&$page)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7), which is called directly after it, is meant for themers to use after all the modules are finished with their business.

I just implemented function `MODULE_page_alter(&$page)`, and it worked in the module as expected.
Did you clear the cache so the module is registered?

Comment: `hook_page_alter()` is thought to be used from modules too; the difference is that `hook_page_alter()` runs after `hook_page_build()`, and it is used to add elements at the page level that depend on another module's elements. Using `hook_page_build()` would not resolve the question being asked: What does `$page['content']` contain?

Comment: Thanks, clearing the cache was the kicker. I didn't know it had anything to do with module processing.

Comment: Also, `drush cc registry` will clear the module_implements() cache -- this means your new hooks will be found by Drupal -- and is usually a *lot* faster than a whole cache clear.

Answer (score 3):

`$page['content']` is not a string, but an array that contains many indexes. As reported in [hook_page_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7), the 'content' element contains the main content of the current page, and its structure will vary depending on what module is responsible for building the page.

When the page is build from the Node and Blog modules, `$page['content']` contains:

- `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['body']`: the node body
- `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['links']`: the array of links attached to the node
- `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['#node']`: the node object
- `$page['content']['system_main']['pager']`: the pager for the results.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's accessed at `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid][<fieldname>]`.
I've been wondering if it can also be accessed with [hook_node_view_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7).

As for `dpm()`, it does 2 weird things for me:

- It doesn't work on `$page`, but does on a sub-element such as `$page['content']`.
- You have to click on another page for it to display. An answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271671/drupal-understanding-how-to-print-variables explains why it only appears on a subsequent page.  It appears for me by clicking on Admin->Configuration->Development->Performance afterwards. (I put a link to it in the Admin Shortcuts bar.)

Comment: This doesn't answer what `$page['content']` contains.

Comment: I've had problems using `dpm()` on the `$page` array as well. I believe it has to do with the fact that, after the first time you do it, you're dpm()ing a page with dpm() output already in it (in the messages block), and this just blows up Kruomo (no idea why).